# How to know in which cell the button is being tapped using Delegate method. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

So i have `userListTableViewController` and `userListTableViewCell` in which i am connecting the `followButton` .. this is the code of my `userListTableViewCell`

```
import UIKit

class userListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

// IBOutlets..


@IBOutlet var followButton: UIButton!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

    func createButton(delegate:AnyObject){

    followButton.addTarget(delegate, action: "followButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)


  }

 }
```

and this is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code:

```
myCell.createButton(self)
```

and this is the func of `followButtonTapped` in `userListTableViewController`

```
 func followButtonTapped(object:AnyObject) {



    println("button clicked") // ******************** here i want to know in which cell or indexPath the button is being pressed. or maybe when button is being tapped, change the title of that button.


}
```

I need some nice explanation where i've marked "******************". Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm holding at any cell the `NSIndexPath` and assigning it at the `cellForRow`.

At the delegate method I'm returning the cell itself,
(see the `UITableView` delegate functions - they deliver the `UITableView`), So at the delegate function you have the relevant cell, and it has the relevant `NSIndexPath`.

Pay attention - if you assigning the `NSIndexPath` - any change of the cells like adding row or removing one will make the old `NSIndexPath` of the other cells to be not true...

Comment: so if adding and removing of cell happens , what would be the best way for applying the buttons in `UITableViewController`
Dude please help me, i am working on this problem from so long.. please help me out.. See in my app, after signUp `userListTableViewController` shows up where all the users data is being retrieved from parse, now i want to add button to follow them.. so what would be the best way to achieve this.. giving `tag` doesn't work fine when there are many users. :-| Please Help Me Out bro.

Answer (score 0):

Set the button tag to the indexPath.row in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code, and set your `followButtonTapped` method as an `@IBAction` with a `UIButton` parameter, rather than `AnyObject`

So in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` add this:

```
myCell.followButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

and change your `followButtonTapped` method to be:

```
@IBAction func followButtonTapped (sender: UIButton!) {
         println("\(sender.tag) button pressed")
}
```

You will have to connect `followButtonTapped` to your follow button in IB, but then should be good to go.

Answer (score -1):

TableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath function is called on click of cell.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```